# Generating a string from substrings in a dictionary, whilst minimising certain characters being next to each other

Tags: python, list, performance, dictionary, permutation

I want to be able to generate a string from a dictionary containing substrings, whereby I input a string where each character corresponds to the key of the dictionary and it spits out a new string from the associated values to that key. However I also want to minimise certain characters being next to each other.

For example:

```
dict = {'I': ['ATA', 'ATC', 'ATT'], 'M': ['ATG'], 'T': ['ACA', 'ACC', 'ACG', 'ACT'], 'N':['AAC', 'AAT'], 'K': ['AAA', 'AAG'], 'S': ['AGC', 'AGT'], 'R': ['AGA', 'AGG']}

input_str = "IIMTSTTKRI"
```

The output would be a string of the three character substrings associated with each key.However there are many 3 character substrings that could be used, I would like to minimise the number of G's and C's that are next to one another.

I currently have this:

```
n = []

#make list of possible substrings for each character in string 
for i in str:
    if i in dict.keys():
       n.append(dict[i])
#generate all permutations 
p = [''.join(s) for s in itertools.product(*n)]

#if no consecutive GCs in a permutation add to list
ls = []
for i in p:
    q = i.count('GC')    
    if q == 0:
        ls.append(i)
```

Which 'works' but there are a couple of problems. The first (minor one) is that I have to assume the consective "GC" is 0 and for some strings that may not be possible. The second (major one), is its extremely slow for longer strings because it has to generate all permutations.

Can anyone provide a way to improve the speed or an alternative way?

Comment: Do you want to generate all possible strings or just one is enough?

Comment: Do you mean generate all possible strings with a low amount of consecutive "GC" or just generate all possible ones?

Comment: I mean if you only need one string with zero/low amount of GC.

Comment: Yeah that would be ideal

Comment: Do all substrings start with `A`? Can all calls to a particular key use the same substring? I'm trying to understand why you can't avoid those substrings containing `GC` or `CG` whenever there is an alternative option.

Comment: Threy do in the example I've provided, however my actual dictionary is much larger and may start with G, C or T

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, you can look at the problem as a optimal path searching (Think about your problem as a graph where you must follow path defined in `input_str` and in each vertex you must chose from a list of defined 3-character wide strings).

There are many search algorithms, my solution is using [A*Star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm):

```py
from heapq import heappop, heappush

dct = {
    "I": ["ATA", "ATC", "ATT"],
    "M": ["ATG"],
    "T": ["ACA", "ACC", "ACG", "ACT"],
    "N": ["AAC", "AAT"],
    "K": ["AAA", "AAG"],
    "S": ["AGC", "AGT"],
    "R": ["AGA", "AGG"],
}


input_str = "IIMTSTTKRI"

def valid_moves(s):
    key = input_str[len(s) // 3]
    for i in dct[key]:
        yield s + i


def distance(s):
    return len(input_str) - (len(s) // 3)


def my_cost_func(_from, _to):
    return _to.count("GC")


def a_star(start, moves_func, h_func, cost_func):
    """
    Find a shortest sequence of states from start to a goal state
    (a state s with h_func(s) == 0).
    """

    frontier = [
        (h_func(start), start)
    ]  # A priority queue, ordered by path length, f = g + h
    previous = {
        start: None
    }  # start state has no previous state; other states will
    path_cost = {start: 0}  # The cost of the best path to a state.
    Path = lambda s: ([] if (s is None) else Path(previous[s]) + [s])
    while frontier:
        (f, s) = heappop(frontier)
        if h_func(s) == 0:
            return Path(s)
        for s2 in moves_func(s):
            g = path_cost[s] + cost_func(s, s2)
            if s2 not in path_cost or g < path_cost[s2]:
                heappush(frontier, (g + h_func(s2), s2))
                path_cost[s2] = g
                previous[s2] = s


path = a_star("", valid_moves, distance, my_cost_func)
print("Result:", path[-1])
```

This prints:

```
Result: ATAATAATGACAAGTACAACAAAAAGAATAAGT
```

Comment: This definitely is faster than my approach, however  for the purpose of this code I need to  have an input string of a couple hundred characters and this code remains very slow for this.  Do you have any suggestions to optimise the speed.

Comment: @DanynPatel You could probably use specialized library for path finding, such as [`networkx`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.astar.astar_path.html) instead of generic one.

Comment: Okay cool, ill give that  a go. I knew there would be an algorithm somewhere for my purpsoe didnt know what one would work though. Thank you.